# What is the best way to disable elements in a form if it is signed?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a logic when users might be presented with a form values, but should be unable to change it if it is "signed". I am wondering what is the best way to do it from controller. Right now, all elements go through the loop and get "disabled" attribute if signature exist. I wonder if I can apply more elegant way on form creation.

This is what I have (and the "disabled" is not assigned to fieldsets this way):

**EDIT 1 - added forms creation**

```
    $form = $sl->get('FormElementManager')->get($formName);

    $hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager);

    $form->setHydrator($hydrator);

    if($isSigned)
    {
        $formElements = $form->getIterator();          
        foreach($formElements as $element )
        {                
            $element->setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you create the form? I agree that this should not go into the controller. Maybe just implement your own Form factory, that will accept $isSigned as an attribute. Inside create the form via standard form factory and then iterate.

Comment: Since I have many different forms, and all of them have this condition, I am thinking to some sort of FormService where all forms will be created, and returned to controller.